# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "emitter" argument must be an instance of EventEmitter. Received type string ('message') discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a ping pong command and I am getting an error saying that `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "emitter" argument must be an instance of EventEmitter. Received type string ('message')` on line 11. Here's my code:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const settings = require("./settings.json");

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
  ]
});

Client.on("message", (msg) => {
  // Message function
  if (msg.author.bot) return; // Ignore all bots
  if (msg.content.startsWith(settings.prefix)) return; // It always has to starts with the prefix which is '!'

  if (msg.content.startsWith(settings.prefix + "ping")) {
    // When a player does '!ping'
    msg.reply("Pong!"); // The bot will say @Author, Pong!
  }
});

Client.login(token);
```

This is the error I get:

```
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('emitter', 'EventEmitter', emitter);
        ^    
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "emitter" argument must be an instance of EventEmitter. Received type string ('message')
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at eventTargetAgnosticAddListener (node:events:1008:11)
    at Function.on (node:events:1095:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\yybro\discordBot\dex.js:11:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
      code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
```

And this is my `settings.json` file:

```json
{
    "clientId": "123456789012345678",
    "guildId": "876543210987654321",
    "token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: Please regenerate your bot token immediately as someone can take it and can make your bot do something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the import for your token like that:

```
const { token } = require('./settings.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `client` which is the instance of the `Client` class you made on line 4, and not `Client` which is the class itself.

Your line 11 should look like that: `client.on('message', msg => {` and same for `client.login(token);` on the last line.

Comment: its now giving a reference error ReferenceError: token(my token i used) is not defined

Comment: You need to define the token somewhere. Did you put it in the `settings.json` file ? If yes you can try doing: `settings.token` instead of `token`.

Comment: its now saying token is not defined Client.login(settings.token);

Comment: You need to add the token inside the `settings.json` file.

Comment: i did that already still the same thing

Comment: Can you edit your post and show us the `settings.json` file?

Comment: Try `console.log(settings)` before you login to the client so that we can see if it is actually getting the details

Comment: If the issue related to the post's title and description has already been solved mark the answer as correct. If you now have new problems considering posting a new question